# How is Prediction by Partial Matching Useful for Data Compression

Tags: algorithm, compression, matching, prediction

So far I know that PPM generates a conditional probability of the next character based on the previous K characters using a dictionary, from researching [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching) and [Guy Blelloch's Introduction to Compression](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/realworld/compression.pdf). However, I still don't understand how PPM helps compress a file like DEFLATE or Burrows-Wheeler. PPMC seems to be a compression algorithm based on PPM, but I cannot find any helpful benchmark comparisons of it with other major algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find benchmarks [here](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html). The best-performing compressors are all PPM or context-mixing compressors, which combine multiple models. They all predict the next bit, not the next byte.